# SLLN with dependent Bernoullis implies convergence of sum with conditional means?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Suppose I have $n$ bernoulli (values zero or one), possibly dependent and nonidentically distributed, random variables (like the generalized binomial model), where a law of large numbers holds. Let $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{S_n-ES_n}{n}=0\text{ a.s.}$$

My question is, does this imply a function like
$$F(n)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor ES_n \rfloor}(ES_n-i)\Pr(S_n=i)+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=\lfloor ES_n \rfloor+1}^n(i-ES_n)\Pr(S_n=i) $$
also converges to zero almost surely?

My work: $$nF(n) = \Pr(S_n\leq ES_n)(ES_n  - E(S_n \mid S_n\leq ES_n)) + (1-\Pr(S_n \leq ES_n))(E(S_n\mid S_n >ES_n )-ES_n) $$

Replacing $\Pr(S_n\leq ES_n)$ with $p_n$,

$$nF(n) = 2p_n ES_n - ES_n - p_nE(S_n \mid S_n\leq ES_n) + (1-p_n)E(S_n \mid S_n> ES_n) $$

$$nF(n) = 2p_n ES_n - 2p_nE(S_n \mid S_n\leq ES_n).$$

Here, I'm getting stuck. I think I can use the tower property to show $EF(n)=0$, but I'd like to show $F(n)\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ a.s.

Comment: Note that your function $F(n)$ is not random, so "convergence almost surely" for $F(n)$ should be replaced by "convergence." And yes, $F(n)$ converges to $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In fact, you just need to assume $(S_n-E[S_n])/n$ converges to $0$ in probability (almost sure convergence is not needed). It is helpful that, in your case,  $0 \leq S_n \leq n$ for all $n$.

You are trying to show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} E\left[\left|\frac{S_n-E[S_n]}{n}\right|\right]=0$. Define $A_n = |S_n-E[S_n]|/n$. A hint is to fix $\epsilon>0$ and consider $E[A_n] = E[A_n|A_n\leq \epsilon]Pr[A_n\leq \epsilon] + E[A_n|A_n>\epsilon]Pr[A_n>\epsilon]$.

More generally, if $\{Z_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of random variables that satisfies $Z_n\rightarrow 0$ in probability, and if the $Z_n$ values are deterministically bounded by some constant $C$ (so that $|Z_n|\leq C$ for all $n$), then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}E[Z_n]=0$. This is a special case of the "Bounded Convergence Theorem" for random variables (see section 13.6 of *Probability with Martingales* by David Williams).

An even more general statement is the "bounded moment convergence theorem," which removes the requirement of deterministic bounds and only requires $E[|Z_n|^{1+\delta}] \leq C$ for all $n$ (for some real numbers $C\geq 0$, $\delta>0$). I needed such a statement once but couldn't find any ref, so I gave a quick proof in Appendix A here: 
http://ee.usc.edu/stochastic-nets/docs/low-power-computing-chapter.pdf

Comment: Thanks! Let me make sure I understand though. In setting up $E[A_n]$, I can show $E[A_n \mid A_n\leq \epsilon]\Pr(A_n\leq \epsilon)+ E[A_n \mid A_n >\epsilon]\Pr(A_n > \epsilon) \leq \epsilon + 1\Pr(A_n > \epsilon) \rightarrow \epsilon$ for a fixed epsilon, which being arbitrary, tells me the expectation is zero? I might also want to weight one kind of "error", adding a constant in front of one of the sums in $F(n)$, but I'm guessing that should be easy enough to deal with.

Comment: Yes, that is a great way to finish the details to show the limiting expectation is $0$. I think this is essentially the same proof as given in the David Williams book.